# How can I know how many times a word is in a file using grep?

Tags: grep

I have a file and I want to know how many times does a word is inside that file.(**NOTE:** A row can have the same word)

Comment: I think you meant that the row in the file could have the same word multiple times.

Comment: Correct, sorry if i was not that clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this command. Hope this wil help you.

```
grep -o yourWord file | wc -l
```

Comment: What if a line contains the word twice?

Comment: My example already count for that. You can try it if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use the grep -c option to count the number of occurences of a search pattern.

```
grep -c searchString file
```

Comment: this is wrong. `grep -c` does count, but for matching lines, not occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

awk solution:

```
awk '{s+=gsub(/word/,"&")}END{print s}' file
```

test:

```
kent$  cat f
word word word
word
word word word

kent$  awk '{s+=gsub(/word/,"&")}END{print s}' f
7
```

you may want to add word boundary if you want to match an exact **word**.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i know you want a `grep` solution, but my favorite perl with the rolex operator can't missing here... ;)

```
perl -0777 -nlE 'say $n=()=m/\bYourWord\b/g' filename
#                              ^^^^^^^^
```

if yoy want match the `YourWord` surrounded with another letters like `abcYourWordXYZ`, use

```
perl -0777 -nlE 'say $n=()=m/YourWord/g' filename
```